# Boolean type checking

Tags: functional-programming

I don't have a much experience in functional programming, but I have read a certain amount of theory papers and I want to build a new type system anyway, because I want implement some improvements. I'm wondering if certain properties I want to achieve already exist in Haskell and company.

One of them would be the following: I want to mix in Boolean operators and/or/not with type checker. That way, when type-checking each iteration in curried function, I want to check it against a Boolean expressions like:

```
((is of type x) OR (is of type y)) AND NOT (is of type z)
```

It would be something like set algebra, dealing with unions, intersections and complements, but implemented using basic Boolean operations that operate on expressions being constrained to types.

I'm aware of sum and product types (sum rings some bells as *or*), but I still can't wrap my head around above expression without implementing *and* and *not* at low level, directly into the type system.

For example, if we introduce imaginary `*` as and, `+` as or, `-` as not, how could we form the semantically same type as:

```
foo: ((x + y) * -z) -> w
```

I'm defining x, y, z and w previously, as some existing types. In this example, function foo has a single parameter that accepts an element of the set ((x union y) intersect (not z)).

Would this kind of Boolean type checking be something new, or it is something that is already achievable in existing functional languages, including Haskell? If it is possible, how would the above *and*, *or* and *not* be implemented in Haskell, or possibly other functional languages?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an operator or function where this type system will be used?

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Be sure to give details to explain how the type system will be used in the example.

Comment: Also be sure to either use valid Haskell syntax or clearly describe the syntax which you invent.

Comment: I think it's pretty much useless to negate a type. What kind of function would you imagine that, say, takes as its argument "anything except an int"?

Comment: perhaps `(float intersect (not int))`

Comment: @ivanv that hardly makes sense, as `float` and `int` do not intersect anyway.

Comment: negation has some interesting properties when implementing propositional, predicate or higher order logic. If we use a bottom type as false, its negation, true, would be a top type.

Comment: `float` and `int` intersect at int. `float` and `not int` intersect at float without int. I'm using float and int just as an example, but rather uninteresting example. Some more useful examples could be formed when dealing with databases, which I'm interested in supporting. So, instead of SQL, we could use set operations to manage data, supported by a power of functional paradigm, which leads us to formation of artificial knowledge base that can store and access types, functions and data in a unified environment.

Comment: @ivanv I think you then meant something like `float ∩ ¬map(int_to_float, int)`.

Comment: I think to make your expression meaningful - especially the `-z` part, I think you have to have a notion of subtyping like `float > int` or to construct things like ```f :: Integral a => (a `OR` Double) `not` Integer)``` which also seems weird. I think in haskell you can achieve part of your "algebra" with type families and type classes. - I would take a look at Idris, a dependently typed programming language.

Comment: You probably want to google for "intersection types" / "union types". It is well known that these are hard to handle by the type checker: I can't remember clearly now, but it's possible that with them type inference, or even type _checking_ (!) becomes undecidable. If you can't find a good reference, on CS.SE surely someone can help.

Comment: @chi Thanks for the googling tips. It seems this is not a new idea: [Elaborating intersection and union types](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~joshuad/papers/intcomp-jfp/Dunfield14_elaboration.pdf); [A Gentle Introduction to Semantic Subtyping](https://www.irif.fr/~gc/papers/icalp-ppdp05.pdf)